# propagate_const of const unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, unique-ptr

The following example is taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <experimental/propagate_const>

struct X
{
    void g() const { std::cout << "g (const)\n"; }
    void g() { std::cout << "g (non-const)\n"; }
};

struct Y
{
    Y() : m_ptrX(std::make_unique<X>()) { }

    void f() const
    {
        std::cout << "f (const)\n";
        m_ptrX->g();
    }

    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "f (non-const)\n";
        m_ptrX->g();
    }

    std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<X>> m_ptrX;
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    y.f();

    const Y cy;
    cy.f();
}
```

I want to further ensure the pointer (`m_ptrX`) address is not modifiable, so I changed the declaration to

```
std::experimental::propagate_const<const std::unique_ptr<X>> m_ptrX;
```

But it doesn't work, gcc 9 reports the following error (see [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=42f1a59eb6a1c3d2) for detail)

```
g++ -std=c++2a -pthread  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread -pedantic-errors main.cpp -lm  -latomic -lstdc++fs  && ./a.out

In file included from main.cpp:3:

/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/experimental/propagate_const: In instantiation of 'constexpr std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<_Tp>::element_type* std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<_Tp>::get() [with _Tp = const std::unique_ptr<X>; std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<_Tp>::element_type = X]':

/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/experimental/propagate_const:205:13:   required from 'constexpr std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<_Tp>::element_type* std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<_Tp>::operator->() [with _Tp = const std::unique_ptr<X>; std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<_Tp>::element_type = X]'

main.cpp:24:15:   required from here

/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/experimental/propagate_const:225:25: error: invalid conversion from 'const element_type*' {aka 'const X*'} to 'std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<const std::unique_ptr<X> >::element_type*' {aka 'X*'} [-fpermissive]

  225 |  return __to_raw_pointer(_M_t);

      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~

      |                         |

      |                         const element_type* {aka const X*}
```

So what is the correct way to achieve the effect, assuming I don't want to implement a template like `immutable_unique_ptr`.

Comment: This `propagate_const` looks like another boilerplat-y thing that you will probably want to stick to almost every member pointer in your class. It has its reasons, it makes sense, but it makes the code longer and longer...

Comment: It compiles on my system readily with GCC 9.2 C++14 and above. May be it is system specific? Also see this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nL9huBh5yJVc11Ks

Comment: @AniketChowdhury The question is why it doesn't work when `std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<X>> m_ptrX;` is replaced by `std::experimental::propagate_const<const std::unique_ptr<X>> m_ptrX;`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems not possible to protect `std::unique_ptr` against modification by  making it `const` in `std::experimental::propagate_const`, but to understand why, we have to go through source code of `std::experimental::propagate_const`, it is available at [propagate_const](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/propagate_const) .

`propagate_const` have a private variable,

```
private:
      _Tp _M_t;
```

So when you create object `std::experimental::propagate_const<const std::unique_ptr<X>> m_ptrX;`, here `_Tp` is template parameter and it will deduce to `_Tp = const std::unique_ptr<X>`

Now error reported at `m_ptr->g();` line of `void Y::f()`, non const overload of `f`, so let's go through all function calls of `propagate_const`.

So `m_ptr->g()` make call to non const `operator->()` of `propagate_const` and which have following implementation,

```
constexpr element_type* operator->(){
    return get();
}
```

It then calls to `get()`, non const overload because `operator->()` it self is non const overload, Now `get()` have following implementation,

```
constexpr element_type* get(){
    return __to_raw_pointer(_M_t);
}
```

Finally `__to_raw_pointer` is private template function of `propagate_const` and have following overloads,

```
template <typename _Up> static constexpr element_type* __to_raw_pointer(_Up* __u) { return __u; }

template <typename _Up> static constexpr element_type* __to_raw_pointer(_Up& __u) { return __u.get(); }

template <typename _Up>static constexpr const element_type* __to_raw_pointer(const _Up* __u) { return __u; }

template <typename _Up> static constexpr const element_type* __to_raw_pointer(const _Up& __u) { return __u.get(); }
```

Because type of private data member `_M_t` is `const std::unique_ptr<X>` and due to this `__to_raw_pointer(_M_t)` will select last overload and that is,

```
template <typename _Up> 
static constexpr const element_type* __to_raw_pointer(const _Up& __u) { 
     return __u.get(); 
}
```

So this is source of error, return type is `const element_type*` which will deduced to `const X*` but non const overload of `get()`

```
constexpr element_type* get() { 
return __to_raw_pointer(_M_t); 
}
```

have return type `element_type*` which will deduced to `X*`.
It's clear now `const X*` can not convert to `X*` and that is exactly the reported error.

So `std::experimental::propagate_const<const std::unique_ptr<X>> m_ptrX;` will not work.

Comment: But the question is whether that is an implementation bug or whether the standard really does not allow `const std::unique_ptr<X>` as argument for `std::experimental::propagate_const`. I couldn't find any requirement that would forbid it.

Answer (score 4):

tldr bug

The [Library Fundamentals TS v2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4617.pdf) says this about non-const `propagate_const<T>::operator->` (`element_type` is `X`):

> 1. `constexpr element_type* operator->()`
> 2. Requires: `get() != nullptr`
> 3. Returns: `get()`

It is specified in terms of non-const `get`, which is specified thusly:

> 10. `constexpr element_type* get();`
> 11. Returns: `t_` if `T` is an object pointer type, otherwise `t_.get()`.

This is perfectly valid even if `T` is const.

We could look for requirements on the type itself. The TS places requirements on the template argument to `propagate_const` in [propagate_const.requirements], [propagate_const.class_type_requirements], and in Table 4.

All of these requirements are met or do not apply. There is no requirement on `T`'s cv qualification.

The most interesting sentence I can find is in the statement [propagate_const.class_type_requirements]/1:

> In this sub-clause `t` denotes a non-const lvalue of type `T`, `ct` is a `const T&` bound to `t`, `element_type` denotes an object type.

This sentence is the subject of [LWG issue 3136](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-unresolved.html#3136), but that does not help illuminate it except to imply that it was maybe not drafted in typical style or is drafted sloppily

One could perhaps argue that that this clause is implicitly requiring that it be possible to have a non-const lvalue of type `T` and thus `T` cannot be const. That seems strained. The clause is applying constraints on a non-const lvalue of type `T` and not requiring that any such exist. However, it also is applying constraints on a reference to const bound to a non-const lvalue, as opposed to an lvalue of type `const T`. Therefore, the `ct` requirements also do not apply, which is absurd. So, my conclusion is that this is sloppily worded and this sentence is not implicitly forbidding const `T`. The non-const requirements should be not applicable.